# Google Chrome reverted to old style

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools

Needed some help with my Google Chrome, which randomly reverted to this pre-material design style. It happened a few weeks ago and have tried lots of methods to fix it but nothing worked. I also have adblocker installed, but somehow it still shows google ads etc.

It doesn't happen on Firefox.

I have tried reinstalling, changing chrome user, updated chrome to newest version, reinstalling adblock/different extensions, running incognito without extensions etc.

This image shows what it looks like now:

Google search on Chrome:

[image]

However, a normal google search should show something like this (it used to be like this):

Google search on Firefox:

[image]

Comment: @fixer1234 Screenshots are clearly from Windows

Comment: my bad about the tag removed now

Answer (score 0):

Your computer is infected with malware. A quick scan with [malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/) should solve your problem :)

Comment: haha literally just found your topic too man, thanks for replying to yours with the fix, literally had this problem for like couple weeks and was stupidly annoying. i guess its what I get for not having any antivirus lol, windows defender isn't the best.

Comment: @Paul Actually, I have Avast (which is pretty well regarded) and it slipped through. Sometimes those things just happen :)

Answer (score 0):

FIX: Install MalwareBytes and run a scan, has something to do with the registrys etc, after about 2 minutes of scanning, quarantine the results and restart pc. Everything is back to normal.

Answer was found here: [In Chrome, Google search reverted to the old format. How do I change this back to the new format?](https://superuser.com/questions/1284997/in-chrome-google-search-reverted-to-the-old-format-how-do-i-change-this-back-t/1300713#1300713)